# How Fused Location determines if use GPS or Network provider?

Tags: android, gps, location

I am developing an app in Android that reports location to a server, and I was wondering to implement the new released Fused Location API, made by Google. Testing it, indoors and with `setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)`
instantly takes networks providers to get location. So, my question is, what see Google in a few seconds to determine that gps is not a good option? I know that gps provider doesn't works properly indoors, but in my office sometimes (it takes an average of 10 secs) it works. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the library itself is not open-source, but I'm sure we can agree on how it does what your describe above:

*If the GPS provider is disabled, or if the signal is too weak, or if the fix takes too long, then it returns the last known location and/or the network provider's location.*

Seems reasonable. **I guess the network provider serves as a fallback to the GPS provider in `PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY` if GPS is not satisfying.**

**EDIT**

Actually, the documentation says:

> PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY
>
> This will return the **finest** location available.

It does not say it will *only* use GPS or prioritize GPS at all. It will just return the finest location, which is not always GPS, as @cYrixmorten pointed out: in urban areas, wifi spots are often more accurate.

Comment: It seems reasonable for me too, thanks!. Is there some official/unofficial documentation about how it works? I mean, I've found pretty less information around than expected.

Comment: Not only does it work as a fallback. WiFi based positioning often is more accurate in urban environments, so here network provider is sometimes preferred over GPS.

Comment: @cYrixmorten definitely true ;)

Comment: @AgustinZanini added the documentation definition for `PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY` which explains this.

Comment: a lot of thanks to all for responses! In theory, I don't have to be connected to the WiFi to get it's location, do I?  But testing i found much better results connected to WiFi than disconnected (but in range)

Comment: Wifi is not mandatory, is just helps where there is a lot of wifi spots like in cities :) And I believe it is consider a NETWORK_PROVIDER.